# Will everything be perfect in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, hereafter

Is it true that we will never forget something in Jannah? If we read something only once, we will remember it perfectly and permanently? And what if you want to have an imperfection? Like anger or facing dificulty with something, would that be granted to you?

Comment: Yes. Yes. No. No.

Answer (score 1):

peace be upon those who follow guidance,

> Is it true that we will never forget something in Jannah? If we read
> something only once, we will remember it perfectly and permanently?

maybe you know that many people looking in the internet or via other ways how to improve memory which is a hope.

**quran**:

saying of الله the most high:

> يُطَافُ عَلَيْهِم بِصِحَافٍ مِّن ذَهَبٍ وَأَكْوَابٍ ۖ وَفِيهَا مَا
> تَشْتَهِيهِ الْأَنفُسُ وَتَلَذُّ الْأَعْيُنُ ۖ وَأَنتُمْ فِيهَا
> خَالِدُونَ

> [الزخرف: 71](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/index.php?ui=1#aya=43_71&m=hafs&qaree=husary&trans=ar_mu)

> And what if you want to have an imperfection? Like anger or facing
> dificulty with something, would that be granted to you?

**quran**:

saying of الله the most high:

> لَا يَسْمَعُونَ فِيهَا لَغْوًا وَلَا تَأْثِيمًا

> [الواقعة](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/index.php?ui=1#aya=56_25&m=hafs&qaree=husary&trans=ar_mu) : 25

**hadith**:

the prophet محمد ﷺ said:

> فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ لاَ يُحِبُّ الْفَاحِشَ الْمُتَفَحِّشَ

> [الأدب المفرد](https://sunnah.com/search?q=%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%87%D9%8E%20%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%91%D9%8F%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B4%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%91%D9%90%D8%B4%D9%8E)

Answer (score 0):

Jannah is a place that is far from what this world is like.

In Jannah, there is no anger, disgust, envy, jealousy, and all these other negative characteristics in a person. They will be dropped at the gate of paradise.

In Jannah, you’re never going to have to breathe again, eat, sleep, work, study, urinate, defecate, etc. etc.

Everyone will be perfect in Jannah. No body will have any flaws.
My question to you is, why would you want a flaw in Jannah?

Despite your every wish in Jannah being granted, I don’t think anger would even be on your mind nor will the feeling of anger be inside you. Once you enter Jannah, it’ll feel as if anger, jealous, envy, etc. never even existed.

Comment: Hey,man if there is no eating what is purpose of so many foods which is in paradise? There is eating and Allah has kept different from of enjoyment. Please edit.

Comment: @Sadiqur what I mean is eat with hunger. In paradise you’ll be able to eat without the need of feeling hungry. Even if you don’t eat, you’re not going to feel week or exhausted or die.